# Layout android insert images and text field

Tags: android, android-layout

How to achieve the following layout for a simple android application. I have images in drawable file with the size of 144 X 144 px.

[image]

**To achieve the layout I tried using table layout but I am not particular about any layout but following is my code.**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/table_view">

<TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Heading"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/compliment_button"
            android:background="@drawable/imgOne"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/feedback_button"
            android:background="@drawable/imgTwo"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/subscribe_button"
            android:background="@drawable/imgThree"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="New Layout"/>
</TableRow>
```

Using this code I got the following layout. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Also, image sizes are smaller than their normal sizes. I have `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `xdpi` and `xhdp` drawable folder, in all of them I have 144x144px images.

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You have not mentioned any button in the third table row and forgot to apply the weight property. As in this code I am adding a button, weight property and some margin. You can give margin dp as per your requirements.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/table_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Heading" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/compliment_button"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/imgOne" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback_button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/imgTwo" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/imgOne"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/subscribe_button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/imgThree" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yourButton4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/imgThree" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="New Layout" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```